# Connection with database failed oracle 12c

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c

[image: Connection Fail Error EM Express Oracle 12c]

i connected to the sys as sysdba user in oracle 12c and then created a user as follows

```
CREATE USER C##umar IDENTIFIED BY umartariq
   DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS
   TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp;


grant create session to C##umar;
grant create any table to C##umar;
grant Resource to C##umar;

ALTER USER C##umar quota unlimited on USERS;
```

i then granted the EM_EXPRESS_ALL role to C##umar through the Enterprise Manager

i can login to the user but i get this error

[image: Connection Fail Error Details]

how do i fix this ?

Comment: Any particular reason to create user in the container database and not in the pluggable database?

Comment: no i am just learning right now i don't know the differences between container and pluggable databases